# Regex: get string after first occurrence of a character (including it)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get some old links from my site to redirect to the new ones with a 301 redirect instruction. What I need to accomplish is to remove the first part of the string until it matches a hyphen and remove it (including the hyphen)

Example:

```
http://example.com/19731-la-preservacion-de-la-biodiversidad-es-crucial-para-frenar-la-desertificacion-en-zonas-aridas
```

or

```
http://example.com/633-afecta-la-crisis-alimentaria-ya-a-miles-de-personas
```

Should output to:

```
http://example.com/la-preservacion-de-la-biodiversidad-es-crucial-para-frenar-la-desertificacion-en-zonas-aridas

http://example.com/afecta-la-crisis-alimentaria-ya-a-miles-de-personas
```

I have tried so far with
`RewriteRule ^[^-|-](.*)$ $1` and
`RewriteRule ^([^-]*-)(.*)$ $1` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try find `^(([^/]*/)*)[^-]*-(.*)$` replace `$1$3`

Comment: Demo https://regex101.com/r/QSSX8x/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(.*?\/)\d+-(.*)
```

Replace:

```
$1$2
```

[Check This](https://regex101.com/r/hWKaXE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To get a substring after the first occurrence of some character *including it* you may use a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that will match any char(s) other than that character, and then you need to start a capturing group, place the char as the first atom in it, and add `.*)` after:

```
^[^-]*(-.*)$
```

Here, `^[^-]*(-.*)$` matches a whole string, and the first `-` with all the chars after it landing in Group 1 (`$1` replacement in `RewriteRule`).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LIlep/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-` (negated character class)
- `(-.*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `-` and then any 0+ chars
- `$` - end of string.